# Can't connect via AWS Session Manager despite open ports and VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2s installed - one with public IP [EC2-A], the other without [EC2-B].

On both, I have the instance roles required for SSM.
Moreover since I do not have a public IP on EC2-B, I created a VPC endpoint (configured correctly, as prior to the creation of the EC2-B endpoint it was not visible in the fleet manager). Both EC2s are visible in `System Manager -> Fleet Manager -> Managed Nodes` .

However, I am unable to connect to *EC2-B* Using AWS System Manager `(aws ssm start-session)`

```
➜  Downloads aws ssm start-session --target i-06d10s2296494c8788


An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation: i-06d348796494c8788 is not connected.
```

but when I add the public IP to EC2-B I can do so.

I have the same roles and security group on both EC2s (everything opened for testing).
EC2-A works as expected.

View from EC2 -> Connect

[image]

Same IAM on *EC2-A* and on *EC2-A* there is no error.

Any help guys?

Comment: Is the security group of the VPC endpoint allowing connections on port 443 from the instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-create-vpc.html#vpc-requirements-and-limitations

Comment: @Ipizzinidev yes, opened everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys for future viewers.

It was not enough to create just one endpoint.

You need 3:

[image]

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/automated-configuration-of-session-manager-without-an-internet-gateway/